# Morris graph year x axis

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/wb6jz/

I have problem with x axis, I want to display dates, not year, where do I define this?

```
    Morris.Area({
  element: 'area-example',
  data: [
    { y: '1.1.', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2.1.', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '3.1.', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '4.1.', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '5.1.', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '6.1.', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '7.1.', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```

Comment: Where are these dates? Or even years? I see arbitrary data values. More info is needed.

Comment: appears from the fiddle that the first arg '1.1', '2.1' etc are interpreted as dates, starting at 1901, 1902 ... using '2007.1.12' dropped in a data point at that date. So sounds like it's just proper formatting needed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your `y` is formated correctly, but if you want to see dates instead of years add `xLabels: "day"`

See http://jsfiddle.net/wb6jz/1/

Documentation: http://www.oesmith.co.uk/morris.js/lines.html

Comment: Yes, but how I can display dates without year, just day?

Comment: Look into the `xLabelFormat` option

Answer (score 0):

First you correct the date formate on Y. Then add `xLabels: "day",`

Here is example

```
Morris.Line({
  element: 'line-example',
  data: [
    { y: '2015-01-01', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2015-02-01', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2015-03-01', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2015-04-01', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2015-05-01', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2015-06-01', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2015-07-01', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
  xkey: 'y',
  ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
  xLabels: "day",
  labels: ['Series A', 'Series B']
});
```